# Performing simultaneous observable requests in angular2/ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, rxjs

Am new to angular2 and ionic2 and i would like to perform two requests after another successifull request

That is after a successifull login i would like to check if the returned token has access rights on the server an then redirrect the user accordingly

This is what i have tried but doesnt work

```
  redirrect(token: string) {

//console.log(token)  returns value of the token

       if (this._authservice.checkAccessRights(token, "is-marshal")) {
           this._navCtrl.setRoot(MarshalPage);

      } else if(this._authservice.checkAccessRights(token, "can-read")) {

           this._navCtrl.setRoot(UserPage);

      } else {

      //force logout then redirrect to login page
         return this._authservice.logout()
            .subscribe(() => {
            this.showtoast("No access rights");
            this._navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
         },
       error=>this.handleError())
    }

   }
```

This is the _authservice

```
  checkAccessRights(usertoken: string, permission: string): Observable<any>             
    {
         let headers = new Headers();
         headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + usertoken);

      return this._http.post(this.authurl +"can-access",permission)
       .map((response: Response) => {
           return response;  //this response is true or false from server
         });
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkAccessRights` returns an observable, you need to subscribe and check for true/false. Currently you are simply checking if an observable is returned.

Try:

```
    redirrect(token: string) {

    //console.log(token)  returns value of the token

          this._authservice.checkAccessRights(token, "is-marshal").subscribe(
              data=>{
               data?
                  this._navCtrl.setRoot(MarshalPage):
                       this._authservice.checkAccessRights(token, "can-read").
                       subscribe(data=>{
                        if(data)
                         this._navCtrl.setRoot(UserPage);
                        else
                          this._authservice.logout()
                              .subscribe(() => {
                                this.showtoast("No access rights");
                                this._navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
                                },
                               error=>this.handleError());

          //force logout then redirrect to login page

                         });

          });
}
```

With switchmap:

```
  redirrect(token: string) {


             canRead$ = this._authservice.checkAccessRights(token, "can-read").switchmap(data=>data?Observable.fromPromise(this._navCtrl.setRoot(UserPage)).mapTo(true)):
    this._authservice.logout().mapTo(false));

             marshal$ = this._authservice.checkAccessRights(token, "is-marshal").switchmap(data=>{data? Observable.fromPromise(this._navCtrl.setRoot(MarshalPage)).mapTo(true):
    canRead$);
                        marshal$.subscribe(data=>{
                             if(!data){
                                    this.showtoast("No access rights");
                                    this._navCtrl.setRoot(LoginPage);
                                    },
                                   error=>this.handleError());

              //force logout then redirrect to login page

                             });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this do you have a particular resource that i can learn more on observables i havent found a goodone yet

Comment: I think this solution has too many nested subscription. With `switchMap` you could eliminate the nesting.